# Cannot stop Tornado for pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, tornado

I currently have the problem, that I cannot test our tornado webserver.
First of all: Tornado is running on a separate thread.

My Wrapper Class is defined as follows:

```
class TornadoProvider():
        def Stop(self):
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop)
            
        def Start(self):
            asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
            application = tornado.web.Application([
                (r'/', VibraSocket),
                (r'/api/message', MessageHandler),
                (r'/api/settings', SettingsHandler),
                ], debug=True)
            application.listen(8080)
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I can use this class in our application with:

```
self.TornadoServer = TornadoProvider.TornadoProvider()
threading.Thread(target=self.TornadoServer.Start).start()
```

and kill it with:

```
self.TornadoServer.Stop()
```

The main problem now is, that when I run pytest, the testcases run through and succeed, but afterwards pytest is stuck in an endless loop. This issue occurs, because the Tornado IO Loop is not stopped. I literally tried everything (even manually call the Stop-Method before the assertions) but it has no effect. Below is the code of my test class.

```
class TestTornadoApiCalls:
    TornadoServer = None

    def setup_class(self):
        self.TornadoServer = TornadoProvider.TornadoProvider()
        threading.Thread(target=self.TornadoServer.Start).start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    def test_send_message(self):
        message = Message(MessageTypes.Notification, datetime.now(), "Test")
        endpoint = "..."
        response = requests.post(url = endpoint, data = message.ToJson())
        assert response.text == "OK"

    def test_get_settings(self):
        endpoint = "..."
        response = requests.get(url = endpoint)
        with open('./Files/settings.json', 'r') as file:
            data = json.loads(file.read())
            assert response.text == str(data).replace("'", "\"")

    def teardown_class(self):
        self.TornadoServer.Stop()
```

Maybe someone can lead me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IOLoop.instance()` returns a thread-specific instance of `IOLoop`. That means when you call it in `Start`, it returns the instance you created for the thread, but in `Stop`, it returns the IOLoop instance for the main thread (which you never actually run). You must save the IOLoop object created in Start, and in Stop refer to *that* object instead of the one that `IOLoop.instance()` returns in the main thread.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Worked like that like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

By default, child thread of Python continues to run even if parent thread dies. But give `Thread` parameter `daemon=None`, and child thread which has no parent will die. Or you should `join()` in `teadown_class()`.

See [explain of `Thread` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

Comment: Both, your and Ben Darnells solution worked. Since I ran into some troubles within automated CI/CD unit tests I also included your solution with `daemon = None` and now it does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!